# android wifi state changed with broadcast receiver

Tags: android

If the user has left the app via the back button key and the app contains a broadcast receiver for wifi state changed will a change in the wifi state trigger the 'left' app receiver and resume the app?   Or will the receiver only work while the app is visible?

Comment: Why you just don't unregister it on destroy and so avoid that risk?

Comment: @Knickedi because maybe they want that exact behaviour so the app can still work in the background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have registered for the intent-filters in your AndroidManifest.xml, the receiver will be called regardless of whether or not your app is in the foreground or even running. The BroadcastReceiver will be garbage collected the moment onRecieve is done though, thus you are not allowed to do any threading in the BroadcastReceiver. You are limited to starting an activity or binding to a service.

Comment: Thats the answer I was hoping for.  Thanks